# @synthesize the "_" notation

Tags: iphone, properties, synthesize

It's clear that the @synthesize define the setter and getter for the object.

But it is unclear to me that:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
```

What does it mean? And why not just implement it in the following way:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

which seems much easier?

Plus, is it related to the lazy programming, which means that you have to write the setter and getter urself?

Hope that someone could help;)

Comment: you dont need to synthesize anymore at all, since xcode 4.2(?), it will be added implicitly as `@sythesize foo = _foo;` so the laziest programming would be to not synthesize and use underscore. But not checking the documentation is not lazy programming — that is just being too lazy.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a *convention* people use to give the property and the iVar separate names. The property will be called `managedObjectContext` and the iVar will be called `_managedObjectContext`.

If they both are named the same it can be fairly easy to confuse them, and mixing them up them can give unexpected results, since using the iVar name will bypass any setters and getters on the property.

Other than that, it has no real function.

Comment: So when should I implement it in this way? Cuz usually we just simply synthesize it as the latter one does, for example, @synthesize certainButton;

Comment: Plus, is it related to the lazy programming, which means that you have to write the setter and getter urself?

Comment: @JackieLam Think of it more as a convenience than a rule. It just renames the iVar to make it harder to confuse the two, it makes absolutely no difference in the function of either the iVar or the property. Compare for example to indentation in ObjectiveC, it's convenient for readability and many people do it, but makes no difference in the functionality of the code.